# Microsoft Project: Is it now possible to set or change a Unique ID of a task?

Tags: ms-project, unique-id

In Microsoft Project, the only way to reset Unique IDs in the past was to change all Unique IDs in a file. This is rarely done but possible to do if someone happened to want the schedule to have Unique IDs in ascending order like the Task IDs. Recently, I was asked if it was now possible to set or change the Unique ID of a singular task. I don't believe that you can and I haven't found any documentation from Microsoft that says that this is possible. Does anyone know if you can in fact set or change the Unique ID of a single task?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Nothing has changed--the Unique ID is a calculated field which is another way of saying it's unchangeable by the user.

A very quick search leads to the documentation: [Unique ID fields](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-id-fields-9d8c0bcf-7fd7-40af-8b37-e32f627aa5e7) which states:

The Unique ID field contains the number that Microsoft Office Project automatically designates whenever a new task, resource, or assignment is created in the current project. This number indicates the sequence in which the task, resource, or assignment was created, regardless of placement in the schedule.

There are several categories of Unique ID fields.

**Data Type**    Integer

**Unique ID (task field)**

**Entry Type**    Calculated

**How Calculated**    As you create new tasks, Project adds a unique number to each task in the project. This number is unique in that it is never rearranged or reused if the task is moved or deleted.